# How to upload javascript files to CPanel File Manager correctly?

Tags: javascript, cpanel

I have external javascript files for my website that I've tested on my computer, and I am now trying to upload to the CPanel file manager.

I have uploaded the .js files in a folder called 'js' in the public_html directory. Two things happened. First, CPanel does not seem to recognize that the files are javascript files, and labels them as 'text/x-generic', and second, when I try to load the relevant page of my website, there are errors that say 'Fail to load resource' when I try to call the javascript functions.

[image: CPanel Folders]

[image: CPanel File]

[image: Failed to Load Resource]

I have tried to find a solution online but found nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered the answer.

when I put the src in the script in the html file, I put "src = 'js/contractorDataInput.js'"

when it should have been "src = '/js/contractorDataInput.js'".

I attribute this error to my lack of programming knowledge.